# how to write procedure?

Tags: mysql

```
zone_id(PK)   ZoneName
-----------   --------
1             east
2             west
3             north
4             south

tbluser

usrId(PK) userzoneId(FK to tblzone)   username
--------  -------------------------   ------------
1         1                           manish
2         3                           rahul
3         2                           ankit
4         4                           amir
5         2                           rashmi
6         1                           akash
tbldoctor

docId(PK)    usrId(Fk to tbluser)      docname
--------     --------------------      ------------
1             2                        hemant
2             2                        chintu
3             3                        rahim
4             1                        salman
5             3                        kishor
6             3                        saurabh
7             2                        banti

tblmedAssign 

transId(Pk)  doctorId(FK to tbldoctor)    medId(FK)    dateInsert
----------   -------------------------    ------   -----------
1            2                            2        20/12/2012
2            3                            3        21/12/2012
3            2                            3        23/12/2012
4            4                            1        24/12/2012


tblunnormalize
 transId(Pk)       docname    username  ZoneName  dateInsert
-------------      -------    --------  --------  ----------
```

what i want is there is one unnormalize table which contains the data related to all these tables. is it possible to write procedure to insert data on run time means when data is inserted in tblmedAssign Table data should inserted on a specific time in unnormalize table?

Comment: What is the structure on that unnormalize table ? And you can do this writting a `AFTER INSERT` trigger.

Comment: If you are not getting. let me know.

Comment: I got that. Ok should right a stored procedure in which after making entries in `tblmedAssign` do related entry in `tblunnormalize`. The problem with trigger in MySql is that they do not allow dynamic SQL. So Stored Procedure is good option.

Comment: I am new at mysql can you help me out? how to write it and commit it?

Comment: Ok....just give me some minutes....

Comment: @hemu are getting any difficulty ?

Comment: No I was on another stuff. Just written Stored Procedure in answer. Let me know if any problem with procedure. thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `medAssignProcedure`$$

CREATE

    PROCEDURE medAssignProcedure(IN transId INT, IN doctorId INT, IN medId INT )

    BEGIN
    DECLARE doctorname VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE user_Name VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE zone_name VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE userId INT;
    DECLARE datetimenow DATETIME;
    SET datetimenow = NOW();
    INSERT INTO tblmedassign VALUES (transId,doctorId,medId,datetimenow);
    SET doctorname = (SELECT docname FROM tbldoctor WHERE docid = doctorId);
    SET userId = (SELECT usrid FROM tbldoctor WHERE docid = doctorId);
    SET user_Name = (SELECT username FROM tbluser WHERE usrid = userId);
    SET zone_name = (SELECT zonename FROM tblzone WHERE zone_id = (SELECT userzoneId FROM tbluser WHERE usrid = userId));   
    INSERT INTO tblunnormalize VALUES (transId, doctorname, user_Name, zone_name, datetimenow);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: do i need to call this procedure? or automatically it will be inserted.

Comment: 1st of all you need to run this code in MySql. Then in your application write the code to call this procedure passing required parameters.